# I am your enemy, hidden in your pleasures. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I am your enemy,
> And I come undercover.
> Better to introduce
> myself as *frenemy*,
> Do you see me inside your lover?
>
> Remember, lust is one of the greatest seven.
> Oh but maybe you're a good person,
> Then I might be a direct flight to heaven.
> If you knew before, would the situation still worsen?
>
> Beware when I come,
> If you are not, I'll be your trouble.
> It might come at a hotel room, or at your own home.
> Ignore me, I dare you double!

Can you find who I am?

**Hint**

> My intention was to post this slightly earlier. But it flew out of my mind.

**Hint 2:**

> Slightly earlier this month.

Comment: This better not be a reference to John Terry and Wayne Bridge...

Comment: @MasterYoda I don't know about those people, but I'm pretty sure it is not :)

Comment: Is the answer a dirthy word? :D

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir nope, it is not dirty :)

Comment: Is "under cover" 2 words on purpose?

Comment: @RnRoger Oh gosh, I always make that mistake, sorry.

Comment: @padawan Wayne Bridge and John Terry were teammates at Chelsea football club. It turned out that Terry was having an affair with Bridges girlfriend at the time causing a big controversy. A few of the lines just made me chuckle

Comment: @MasterYoda Haha. Did not know that. Also, both usernames check out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could the answer be:

> HIV/AIDS?

Following your riddle:

I am your enemy

> Such sickness is definitely your enemy, as it may ultimately kill you.

And I come undercover.

> Seropositivity stays undetected until you go and check for it.

Do you see me inside your lover?

> If ever you get the HIV through your partner, you may keep seeing the virus through him because of your current state?

Remember, lust is one of the greatest seven.

> HIV is transmitted through sexual relations, which can be considered as "lust".

If you knew before, would the situation still worsen?

> If the sick person knew about it before, he could have been treated before, and maybe saved. Or if the partner knew, maybe he wouldn't have got the virus in the first place.

Beware when I come,

If you are not, I'll be your trouble.

It might come at a hotel room, or at your own home.

Ignore me, I dare you double!

> If you don't protect yourself or ignore the sickness, you are taking the risk of getting HIV. As it can be transmitted through sexual relations, it might happen in a hotel room like in your own home.

About the hints:

> The World AIDS Day is on December 1st every year, so it was earlier this month.

Comment: Surely this is the answer, thanks for finding it so I can finally close this browser tab after 4 days

Comment: Yes, exactly. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a loose guess, posting it so I have an excuse to stop staring at the riddle.
Is it

> You yourself? (you as in anyone, not the OP)

Do you see me inside your lover?

> Isn't there such a thing as to see yourself in your partner/lover?

Oh but maybe you're a good person,
Then I might be a direct flight to heaven.

> If you yourself are a good person you go to heaven.

Ignore me, I dare you double!

> "I", which is me, yourself twice, err....

I doubt this is the right answer. I've mostly been thinking of something related to "time" but I can't come up with anything concrete.

Comment: Interesting point of view. Bu this is not it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> Temptation to sin?

Because (stanza 1):

> It is disguised as nice things you could have if you give in to it, but the outcome is immorality - hence a *frenemy*. Inside your lover could refer to infidelity.

and  (stanza 2):

> "lust is one of the greatest seven" refers to the seven deadly sins, one of which is lust. If you are a good person and don't sin, you get a ticket straight to heaven.

and (stanza 3):

> The hotel room could refer to infidelity / an affair (or temptation to steal the bath towels?). The house could refer to excessive house pride. "Ignore me, I dare you double!" - don't give in to temptation.

Not sure what to make of the hint. Possibly:

> Giving in to forgetfulness/procrastination...

Comment: Unfortunately not. And also the hint actually reveals good info :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Forgiveness or purity

Reason

> Just feeling because of some lines will update explanation soon